# Invoking 'initialize' of several included modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I include a module into a class, which has `initialize` defined, I can call it using `super`:

```
module M
  def initialize(x)
    @m = x
  end
end

class MyClass
  def initialize
    super(3)
  end

  def val
    @m
  end
end

MyClass.new.val
#  => 3
```

But how do I code this, if I have several modules, and maybe also a parent class?

```
class Parent
  def initialize(x)
    @p = x
  end
end

module M
  def initialize(x)
    @m = x
  end
end

module N
  def initialize(x)
    @n = x
  end
end

class MyClass < Parent
  include M
  include N
  def initialize
    # ???? How to initialize here?
  end

  def val
    [@m,@n,@p]
  end
end
```

I guess that `super(100)` within `MyClass::initialize` would set the variable `@n`, because `N` is the "most recent" ancestor, but how do I call the `initialize` methods in `M` and `Parent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post (http://stdout.koraktor.de/blog/2010/10/13/ruby-calling-super-constructors-from-multiple-included-modules/). It explains how do you use the `initialize` from different included modules.

Comment: GREAT article!!! I don't think I would have been able to derive this solution by my own. IMO, the current implementation in Ruby - let `super` pick the next `initialize` in the ancestor hierarchy which matches the parameter list and skipping all the others - is bad design point of this language. If there is an `initialize` method, it is there for a reason and it should never be silently skipped....

Comment: The above link is expired. Here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160325173756/http://stdout.koraktor.de/blog/2010/10/13/ruby-calling-super-constructors-from-multiple-included-modules/